# Operations with big ints factorial combination

Tags: java, biginteger

I was trying with `BigInteger` for operations with large numbers, but I see than the *product* operation is very slow, when I'm calculating combinations CnR and factorials.

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
}
```

I'm looking for a best algorithm, inclusive with arrays of ints.

Comment: `for (int i=2; i<=20; i++) {` is a little start but do you really need to multiply by 1?

Comment: With factorials calculations, int is too small.

Comment: Here's some thing on multiplying large numbers http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51894.html.

Comment: Also depending on your needs you could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation to approximate the factorial.

Comment: @Paul he's using a `BigInteger` which is large enough.

Comment: FYI, OP, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides [`BigIntegerMath.binomial`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#binomial(int,%20int)) and [`BigIntegerMath.factorial`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#factorial(int)), which are optimized relatively thoroughly.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman realy nice! Can you say how much faster this implementation is?

Comment: For n around 1000, the factorial implementation is ~9x faster.  The binomial implementation isn't as heavily optimized yet, but it's getting improvements over time -- that's one of the benefits of using a library that other people will optimize for you.

Comment: @trutheality, the recursive formula requires O(nk) additions at best, as opposed to O(k) multiplications and divisions.  The algorithmic difference seems to suggest the performance of that technique would be significantly worse.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: Thanks for all. I see first the Guava implementations and next the fast factorial functions.

Answer (score 1):

Printing to the console is the slowest part of your code. Try not to print in every iteration. It will make your code much (!) faster. The rest looks good. You can use primitive types, this will be a little bit faster than a real class, but not much.

Comment: Sorry. The printing is only for debug.